# Given T(1)=1 and $T(n) = 3T(n/4) + cn^2$, does it make sense to yield $T(2)=T(1)+c2^2$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Section 4.4 of "[Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition
By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein](https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf)" illustrates how a recursion tree provides a good guess for the recurrence

$$T(n) = 3T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + \Theta(n^2) = 3T(n/4) + cn^2$$

where c is a constant.

[image]

The authors assume that n is an exact power of 4.

I agree with the tolerable sloppiness and understand the basic idea of that section.

I'd just like to know about some other trivial details.

For convenience, assume T(1)=1, so $T(4)=3T(4/4)+c4^2=3T(1)+c4^2$, what about T(2) and T(3)?

Does it make sense to yield $T(2)=T(1)+c2^2$?

Similarly, $T(3)=2T(1)+c3^2$?

Comment: Your recurrence is only defined for powers of 4. It is undefined for an input which is not an integer power of 4. In particular, $T(2)$ and $T(3)$ are as meaningless as $T(\pi)$ and $T(\sqrt{-1})$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Per my understanding of the section and some other parts of that book, the recurrence is NOT defined for powers of 4, I prefer that the domain is the set of all positive integers.

Comment: If $n$ is not a multiple of $4$, then $n/4$ is not an integer. Can you run your algorithm on a list of length $3.5$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $\lfloor n/4 \rfloor$ guarantees that there will not be a thing like 3.5.

Comment: Your original post didn’t contain any floors…

Comment: Besides, you might get $T(0)$, so you need an additional initial condition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you. I agree with you on $T(0)$